# Mapbox trail view Android

Tags: java, android, mapbox

how to create clickable trail with info about this trail in Mapbox ? I have trails from GEOJsoN like:

```
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [12.691956, 52.943673],
          [12.727661, 52.912215],
          [12.757874, 52.88902],
          [12.7771, 52.859181],
          [12.799072, 52.822683],
          [12.801819, 52.784492]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In mapbox.com I read it is possible with markers but only when i have 2 diffrents API (trails and marker)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Annotation Plugin which supports event listeners.

1. Create a [Line using the LineManager](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/#manager) using the Annotation Plugin.
2. [Add a clickListener](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/#listeners) to that LineManager.
3. Define the action that should be executed when the Line is clicked on:

```js
lineManager.addClickListener(new OnSymbolClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onAnnotationClick(Symbol symbol) {
 
 // Do stuff here
 
}
});
```

Also see [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/symbol-listener/) that adds a onClickListener to a Symbolmanager. It displays a toast when clicked.